# XAML ListView in Xamarin does not work

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, listview, xamarin

I started to learn Xamarin, and i am trying to create first test project. I created the ListView which displays the ObservableCollection from BindingContext. "Take" is a table that has three properties. The problem is, that when i run app on emulator the following eror dialog appears:"Process system isn't responding. Do you want to close it?"
But if i erase tag  and all internal XAML code everything works well, but i want to dispalay values of properties of class "Take" in each element of ListView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="App1.Views.Page1">

<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to my first project"></Label>
        <Label Text="Why does it does not work?"></Label>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding GetList}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Word}"></TextCell>
                    <Button Text="SomeText"></Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And this is my C# BindingContext

```
public class SQLiteSamplePage
{
    private readonly SQLiteConnection _sqLiteConnection;
    private ObservableCollection<Take> list;

    public SQLiteSamplePage()
    {
        _sqLiteConnection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
        _sqLiteConnection.CreateTable<Take>();
        _sqLiteConnection.Insert(new Take
        {
            Word = "SomeWord1",
            Translation = "Some translation 1"
        });

        _sqLiteConnection.Insert(new Take
        {
            Word = "SomeWord",
            Translation = "SomeTranslation"
        });

        list =new ObservableCollection<Take>( _sqLiteConnection.Table<Take>());
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Take> GetList
    {
        get { return list; }
    }
}
```

And here is a code of a table

```
public class Table
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string Word { get; set; } 
    public string Translation { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: try removing the Button from your DataTemplate

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the `TextCell` and the `Button` in a `StackLayout` or any kind of layout inside a `<ViewCell>` element:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding GetList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding Word}"></TextCell>
                    <Button Text="SomeText"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The child of the `DataTemplate` element must be of or derive from type `ViewCell`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine a `TextCell` and something else, in your case a `Button`. If you want to show both Text and the Button you will need to use a custom cell.

This is done using the base class `ViewCell` and inside there you define the layout you want to show

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="Welcome to my first project"></Label>
    <Label Text="Why does it does not work?"></Label>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding GetList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Word}"></Label>
                        <Button Text="SomeText"></Button>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Hope this helps.